# Extract respective upper and lower triangle's elements of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Given square matrix `m` as follows (`nxn`):

```
m <- matrix(1:5,ncol = 5,nrow = 5,byrow = F)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5
```

I want to extract the respective upper and lower triangle's elements and take the relative frequency.

We can naively do that via a loop like this (here `n=5`):

```
for (i in 1:(n-1))
    for (j in (i+1):n){
        x <- m[i,j]
        y <- m[j,i]
        m[i,j] <- x/(x+y)
        m[j,i] <- y/(x+y)
    }
```

Here is the desired output:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000 0.1666667
[2,] 0.6666667 2.0000000 0.4000000 0.3333333 0.2857143
[3,] 0.7500000 0.6000000 3.0000000 0.4285714 0.3750000
[4,] 0.8000000 0.6666667 0.5714286 4.0000000 0.4444444
[5,] 0.8333333 0.7142857 0.6250000 0.5555556 5.0000000
```

Can we generate this output more efficiently?

P.S.

I'm aware of `m[upper.tri(m)]` and `m[lower.tri(m)]`, but it does not the trick because the order of extracted elements are different. For example, `m[upper.tri(m)]` will give me:

```
[1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4
```

While what of I want for the upper triangle is:

```
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

Comment: the deleted answer from @AlexIoannides gives the clue - `?upper.tri` and `?lower.tri` form the basis of a solution ...

Comment: @BenBolker I knew that but it does not the trick.

Comment: @m0h3n have a look at this post https://github.com/gastonstat/matrixkit/blob/master/R/lower-upper-triangular.r

Comment: you can get it done by appropriate combination of `t()` and `upper.tri/lower.tri`, I think ...

Comment: If you supply some testdata, I can have a look. I would try `upper.tri(m)/(m+t(m))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much more easily:

```
f <- m/(m+t(m))
#> f
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000 0.1666667
#[2,] 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.4000000 0.3333333 0.2857143
#[3,] 0.7500000 0.6000000 0.5000000 0.4285714 0.3750000
#[4,] 0.8000000 0.6666667 0.5714286 0.5000000 0.4444444
#[5,] 0.8333333 0.7142857 0.6250000 0.5555556 0.5000000
```

Even the diagonal is calculated this way, but that has no information, so use `diag(f) = diag(m)` to get the desired output.

```
#> f = m/(m+t(m))
#> diag(f) = diag(m)
#> f
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000 0.1666667
#[2,] 0.6666667 2.0000000 0.4000000 0.3333333 0.2857143
#[3,] 0.7500000 0.6000000 3.0000000 0.4285714 0.3750000
#[4,] 0.8000000 0.6666667 0.5714286 4.0000000 0.4444444
#[5,] 0.8333333 0.7142857 0.6250000 0.5555556 5.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining the `lower.tri` with the transpose `t()` we can get the `upper.tri` in the order you wanted

```
t(m)[lower.tri(t(m))]
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

---

To get the desired output we use the same strategy

```
#lower.tri and upper.tri matrices
lt <- m[lower.tri(m)]
ut <- t(m)[lower.tri(t(m))]
#defining the frequency matrix, just so it has the same dimensions of m
f <- m
#we can't assing a value to t(f), so we assing the upper.tri frequency to the lower.tri portion of f, then transpose f
f[lower.tri(f)] <- ut/(lt+ut) 
f <- t(f)
#then the lower.tri portion follows
f[lower.tri(f)] <- lt/(lt+ut)
#> f
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000 0.1666667
#[2,] 0.6666667 2.0000000 0.4000000 0.3333333 0.2857143
#[3,] 0.7500000 0.6000000 3.0000000 0.4285714 0.3750000
#[4,] 0.8000000 0.6666667 0.5714286 4.0000000 0.4444444
#[5,] 0.8333333 0.7142857 0.6250000 0.5555556 5.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution using `combn` (it helps to extract the elements of the upper-triangle in the desired order.):

```
out <- m
inds <- t(combn(ncol(m),2))

 # > inds
      # [,1] [,2]
 # [1,]    1    2
 # [2,]    1    3
 # [3,]    1    4
 # [4,]    1    5
 # [5,]    2    3
 # [6,]    2    4
 # [7,]    2    5
 # [8,]    3    4
 # [9,]    3    5
# [10,]    4    5

denom <- m[inds]+m[inds[,2:1]]

out[inds] <- m[inds]/denom
out[inds[,2:1]] <- m[inds[,2:1]]/denom

out
          # [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,] 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2000000 0.1666667
# [2,] 0.6666667 2.0000000 0.4000000 0.3333333 0.2857143
# [3,] 0.7500000 0.6000000 3.0000000 0.4285714 0.3750000
# [4,] 0.8000000 0.6666667 0.5714286 4.0000000 0.4444444
# [5,] 0.8333333 0.7142857 0.6250000 0.5555556 5.0000000
```

**BENCHMARKING**

```
library(microbenchmark)
m <- matrix(1:5,ncol = 5,nrow = 5,byrow = F)

f_m0h3n1 <- function(m){
    n <- ncol(m)
    for (i in 1:(n-1))
        for (j in (i+1):n){x <- m[i,j];y <- m[j,i];m[i,j] <- x/(x+y);m[j,i] <- y/(x+y);}
    return(m)
}

f_catastrophic_failure1 <- function(m){f <- m/(m+t(m));diag(f) <- diag(m);return(f);}

f_m0h3n2 <- function(m){out <- m;inds <- t(combn(ncol(m),2));denom <- m[inds]+m[inds[,2:1]];out[inds] <- m[inds]/denom;out[inds[,2:1]] <- m[inds[,2:1]]/denom;return(out);}

f_catastrophic_failure2 <- function(m){
    lt <- m[lower.tri(m)];ut <- t(m)[lower.tri(t(m))];f <- m;f[lower.tri(f)] <- ut/(lt+ut);f <- t(f);f[lower.tri(f)] <- lt/(lt+ut);return(f);
}
r <- f_m0h3n1(m)
all(f_m0h3n2(m) == r)
# [1] TRUE
all(f_catastrophic_failure1(m) == r)
# [1] TRUE
all(f_catastrophic_failure2(m) == r)
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(f_m0h3n1(m), f_m0h3n2(m), f_catastrophic_failure1(m), f_catastrophic_failure2(m))

# Unit: microseconds
                       # expr    min      lq      mean median     uq     max neval
                # f_m0h3n1(m) 70.575 73.7825  78.95802 75.707 83.407 131.312   100
                # f_m0h3n2(m) 87.255 90.2500  96.36626 91.533 98.163 244.230   100
 # f_catastrophic_failure1(m) 33.790 35.5010  38.37556 36.785 37.640 142.432   100
 # f_catastrophic_failure2(m) 91.961 95.3825 102.27319 97.735 99.660 303.256   100
```